# Why am I getting metaMDS error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 17 for species matrix? Is this due to an incorrect matrix input?

Tags: r, vegan

Beginner and new to stack:

I get this error message while trying to make NMDS ordination plot for bird community count data.

Data subset:

```
datasubset <- "Cell_ID Treatment Count_cell Bird_Code
1   26-E15-N Single Tree Selection Cut          1      EAWP
2   26-E15-N Single Tree Selection Cut          2      ACFL
4   26-E15-N Single Tree Selection Cut          2      REVI
5   26-E15-N Single Tree Selection Cut          3      AMGO"
bird18_ <- read.table(text=datasubset, header = TRUE)
```

Here is my code:

```
num <- nrow(Bird18_)
new_data_frame <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:num){

mult_by <- bird18_$Count_cell[i]
interimdf <- data.frame(bird18_[i, ])
againdf <- rbind(interimdf[rep(1, mult_by), ])
new_data_frame <- rbind(new_data_frame, againdf)

}

bird_matrix_18<-cast(new_data_frame, Cell_ID+Treatment~Bird_Code) 
vegan_species<-bird_matrix_18[,c(3:39)] #getting rid of plot info

###vegan bray-curtis 
dis_matrix <- vegdist(vegan_species, method = "bray")
###Simper analysis
sim <- with(vegan_plotinfo, simper(vegan_species, Treatment))

lapply(sim, FUN=function(x){x$overall})
sim<-data.frame(unclass(summary(sim)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors  = FALSE)
mds <- metaMDS(vegan_species, distance = "bray", k = 2, trymax = 20,    autotransform = TRUE, noshare = 0.1, expand = TRUE, trace = 1, plot = FALSE)
```

Here is my error:

```
Error in data.frame(rrownames(x), unx, check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 17
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! It would be make it easier for the community to help you if you edited your question to include some sample data along with your code. This is often accomplished with the ```dput()``` function.  This also aids [reproduciblity](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That said, what happens when you change ```bird18_$Count_cell[I]```to ```bird18_$Count_cell[i]``` ?

Comment: Thank you, I tried to include a subset - sorry I couldn't figure out dput() right now. [I] was a typo in the initial post -  thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: BTW, to use ```dput()```, I think you just need to copy-paste the console output of ```dput(bird18_)``` into the code block of your question.

Comment: Thanks, @xilliam thats easier than expected. I found that if I use    `cast()`function differently, I can accomplish what I need to instead of using my`for()`Here is the new`cast()`line I use`bird.matrix.18<-cast(bird18_, CellID+Treatment~Bird_Code,  value = "Count_cell")`This also makes my metaMDS happy and I don't get this error.